# Python open folder and then focus to file

Tags: python, directory, focus

```
import os
os.startfile(path)
```

With the above code i can open a folder in explorer (windows 10)

How can i focus to a specific file?

Example:

[image]

[image]

I search for a solution for most os (windows, ubuntu, mac...)

**Edit:** In windows with

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+path_with_file+'"')
```

it gives me the desired result.